# Access INSERT INTO using DateAdd to update field

Tags: ms-access, select, vba, bulkinsert, dateadd

I am trying to copy records from a mySQL table into an Access table and add 90 days to one of the fields using an Access-VBA SQL statement such as:

INSERT INTO clients (id, ReferralDate, ReferralExpiration) SELECT id, referral.date, DateAdd("d", 90, referral.date) from referral where id > 10;

but I get a syntax error.  Can I do this in 1 statement and if so, what's the correct syntax?

Thanks, Geoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be missing parenthesis.  This worked for me:

```
INSERT INTO clients ( id, ReferralDate, ReferralExpiration)
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.ReferralDate, DateAdd("d",90, ReferralDate) AS Expr1
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.[id])>10));
```

I used the Query Designer to get it right.

Comment: It was actually something else.  I had also started updating a field named "Language" and that was the problem.  I renamed it "PrimaryLanguage" and the syntax error went away.  I never realized that "language" was a reserved name.

-- Geoff

Comment: Accepting answers will encourage people to answer your questions in the future.  Even if you don't feel right accepting this one, your previous question also doesn't have an accepted answer.